# Let $(a_n)$ be a bounded sequence. What does $y_n = \sup\{a_k : k \geq n\}$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

I am having trouble understanding/visualizing what $y_n = \sup\{a_k : k \geq n\}$. What does this mean? I don't want to post the whole question since it is homework but any help for this part is highly appreciated.

Comment: It means that $\;y_n\;$ is the lowest upper bound of the set $\;\{a_n,\ a_{n+1},\,a_{n+2},\ldots\}\;$ This thing is part of the definition of upper limit (and something similar of lower limit) os a sequence.

Comment: Or, take it this way: $y_1$ is the supremum of the whole sequence. Now chop off the first element - make the sequence $a_2, a_3, a_4,\ldots$ and take $y_2$ to be *its* supremum. Now chop off $a_2$, make a new sequence starting with $a_3$ and take $y_3$ to be *its* supremum, and so on. $y_n$'s are in effect suprema of the "tails" of the original sequence $(a_n)$, with the first $n-1$ elements chopped off from the front.

Comment: Is it like the "steps"? For example let $a_n = 1/n$ so $y_n$ would sort of "step down" after cutting off the $a_1$ then $a_2$ then $a_3$ and so on?